# Magnetic engine

Tags: magnetic-fields

Is it possible to mimic crrent engine design (to some extent) by replacing the cylinders with opposed magnets? A device interupts their natural desire to push away from each other allowing them to come together (or atleast closer) at which time the device would retract into the cylinder housing allowing a powerful separation to happen which woud (when the cylinders reach the top or bottom of shaft) create enough force to work the rest of the engine parts in a similar way to current conventional engines? Please excuse me for my  non academic description. This as bugged me for some time now and really have to get it off my chest!!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely could. It almost certainly wouldn't be as efficient as a normal electric motor, but it would work. However, you would have to use some kind of electromagnet instead of permanent magnets. If you still use permanent magnets for the cylinders, you could have them pull as well as push (or you could just use iron cylinders and have the magnets pull). What I think would be coolest would be to use inductive repulsion, like ring launchers ([video](http://www.instructables.com/id/The-Ring-Launcher-Explained-The-Geek-Group/), the explanation isn't great but you can find better).

Again, it's not practical, but the concept is fine.